# Getting entire path string using re (Regular expression) in python

Tags: python, regex

Here's my string:

> `str = """<import namespace="http://schemas.oracle.com/events/edl/EventHandlerDefinition" location="oramds:/apps/Common/Events/EventHandlerDefinition.edl" importType="edl"/>\n   <import namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/GSKICDSApplication/GSKInformICDSSub/getEnrollmentNumDB" location="WSDLs/getEnrollmentNumDB.wsdl" importType="wsdl"/>\n   <import namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/GSKICDSApplication/GSKInformICDSSub/getSitenuemonics" location="WSDLs/getSitenuemonics.wsdl" importType="wsdl"/>\n   <service name="gskTransactions" ui:wsdlLocation="WSDLs/gskTransactions.wsdl">\n      <interface.wsdl interface="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/jms/ICDSApplicationSOA/GSKInformICDSSub/gskTransactions#wsdl.interface(Consume_Message_ptt)"/>\n      <binding.jca config="Adapters/gskTransactions_jms.jca">\n         <property name="useRejectedMessageRecovery" type="xs:string" many="false" override="may">true</property>\n        <property name="singleton" many="false">true</property>\n      </binding.jca>\n   </service>\n   <property name="compositeID" type="xs:string" many="false">594eb06a-5e1f-4577-b005-dd21c07a9979</property>\n   <property name="productVersion" type="xs:string" many="false">12.1.3.0.1</property>\n   <component name="GSKInformICDSSub" version="2.0">\n      <implementation.bpel src="BPEL/GSKInformICDSSub.bpel"/>\n      <componentType>\n         <service name="gskinformicdssub_client" ui:wsdlLocation="WSDLs/gskTransactions.wsdl">\n"""`

I have to get the entire string where the string contains `oramds`:

Output should be :

```
oramds:/apps/Common/Events/EventHandlerDefinition.edl
```

I am using:

```
MDS = re.search(r'\b(\w*oramds\w*)\b', str(search_str))
    print(MDS)
```

but it is giving me only 
    `['oramds']`

I want to list the entire path starting with `oramds:` in the string.

Comment: [`\b(oramds:[^"]+)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/EP53al/1)

Comment: I think the char / doesnt belong in \w so it stops there

Comment: @Davіd your expression gave me till oramds:/apps/Common/Events/EventHandlerDefinition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will only match `oramds` as `\w` will match word characters and will not match for example the dots or the forward slashes.

Instead of using a word boundary `\b`, the string starts with `"oramds:` so you might also match until the closing double quote using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^"]+` and use a capturing group to match the content.

```
"(oramds:[^"]+)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jI6yli/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/be3JzT)

For example

```
import re
search_str = """<import namespace="http://schemas.oracle.com/events/edl/EventHandlerDefinition" location="oramds:/apps/Common/Events/EventHandlerDefinition.edl" importType="edl"/>\n   <import namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/GSKICDSApplication/GSKInformICDSSub/getEnrollmentNumDB" location="WSDLs/getEnrollmentNumDB.wsdl" importType="wsdl"/>\n   <import namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/GSKICDSApplication/GSKInformICDSSub/getSitenuemonics" location="WSDLs/getSitenuemonics.wsdl" importType="wsdl"/>\n   <service name="gskTransactions" ui:wsdlLocation="WSDLs/gskTransactions.wsdl">\n      <interface.wsdl interface="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/jms/ICDSApplicationSOA/GSKInformICDSSub/gskTransactions#wsdl.interface(Consume_Message_ptt)"/>\n      <binding.jca config="Adapters/gskTransactions_jms.jca">\n         <property name="useRejectedMessageRecovery" type="xs:string" many="false" override="may">true</property>\n        <property name="singleton" many="false">true</property>\n      </binding.jca>\n   </service>\n   <property name="compositeID" type="xs:string" many="false">594eb06a-5e1f-4577-b005-dd21c07a9979</property>\n   <property name="productVersion" type="xs:string" many="false">12.1.3.0.1</property>\n   <component name="GSKInformICDSSub" version="2.0">\n      <implementation.bpel src="BPEL/GSKInformICDSSub.bpel"/>\n      <componentType>\n         <service name="gskinformicdssub_client" ui:wsdlLocation="WSDLs/gskTransactions.wsdl">\n"""

MDS = re.search(r'"(oramds:[^"]+)"', str(search_str))
print(MDS.group(1))
```

Output

```
oramds:/apps/Common/Events/EventHandlerDefinition.edl
```

Comment: your expression gave me till oramds:/apps/Common/Events/EventHandlerDefinition i want the .edl extension as well

Comment: ok i got thanks when i used this expression in  re.findall it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

just replace

```py
MDS = re.search(r'\b(\w*oramds\w*)\b', str(search_str))
```

with

```py
MDS = re.search(r'\b(oramds:\S+)\b', str(search_str))
```

And it should just work fine.

**EDIT**

Well I just noticed that you were simply printing `MDS` but when you use search then you need to use `object.group()` to get the matched expression. If you want to avoid using `group()` then you can use `re.findall()` to extract the matched expression.
So your new code will be

```py
import re

search_str = """<import namespace="http://schemas.oracle.com/events/edl/EventHandlerDefinition" location="oramds:/apps/Common/Events/EventHandlerDefinition.edl" importType="edl"/>\n   <import namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/GSKICDSApplication/GSKInformICDSSub/getEnrollmentNumDB" location="WSDLs/getEnrollmentNumDB.wsdl" importType="wsdl"/>\n   <import namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/GSKICDSApplication/GSKInformICDSSub/getSitenuemonics" location="WSDLs/getSitenuemonics.wsdl" importType="wsdl"/>\n   <service name="gskTransactions" ui:wsdlLocation="WSDLs/gskTransactions.wsdl">\n      <interface.wsdl interface="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/jms/ICDSApplicationSOA/GSKInformICDSSub/gskTransactions#wsdl.interface(Consume_Message_ptt)"/>\n      <binding.jca config="Adapters/gskTransactions_jms.jca">\n         <property name="useRejectedMessageRecovery" type="xs:string" many="false" override="may">true</property>\n        <property name="singleton" many="false">true</property>\n      </binding.jca>\n   </service>\n   <property name="compositeID" type="xs:string" many="false">594eb06a-5e1f-4577-b005-dd21c07a9979</property>\n   <property name="productVersion" type="xs:string" many="false">12.1.3.0.1</property>\n   <component name="GSKInformICDSSub" version="2.0">\n      <implementation.bpel src="BPEL/GSKInformICDSSub.bpel"/>\n      <componentType>\n         <service name="gskinformicdssub_client" ui:wsdlLocation="WSDLs/gskTransactions.wsdl">\n"""

MDS = re.search(r'\b(oramds:\S+)\b', str(search_str))
print(MDS.group())
```

However, you might consider reading this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm) to better understand the concepts of regex in python.
Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: your expression gave me till oramds:/apps/Common/Events/EventHandlerDefinition i want till oramds:/apps/Common/Events/EventHandlerDefinition.edl

Comment: I am getting the desired output. When I am printing the result, it is showing the `.edl` extension

Comment: @ShrikantGourh I have edited my answer with necessary clarification for your better understanding.